# Assigning object values from return of another class' function?

Tags: java, function, interface, static

So after completing the last assignment I was given, I was instructed to take that code and change it from command line arguments to reading in data from a file. That all works out well, except for the part where I'm supposed to have an interface for a function that calls in the data from the file, then does the same things as before.

Right now, the object array in my driver class is SUPPOSED to be assigned the values taken in by the DAO class. The DAO class is based off the interface. The driver class is screaming at me that the object I have created has to be assigned from a static function in the DAO class, but that method can't be static...

What did I miss this time?..

Interface:

```
public interface ScanTextFile {

    public Object[] readTextData() throws FileNotFoundException;
}
```

DAO Class:

```
public class StudentDAO implements ScanTextFile {

    public Object[] readTextData() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Student[] studentRecord = new Student[3];

        String dataFileName = "data.txt";
        int numberOfRows = 0;

        File dataFile = new File(dataFileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(dataFile);
        int i = 0;
        String delim = "\\|";

        // checks number of rows in data file, making sure there are 3 total
        for(i = 0; scan.hasNextLine(); i++){
            numberOfRows++;
        }
        if(numberOfRows < 3){
            System.err.format((numberOfRows) + " argument(s) - expected 3");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if(numberOfRows > 3){
            System.err.format((numberOfRows) + " arguments - expected 3");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for(i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
            if(scan.hasNextLine()){
                String temp = scan.nextLine();
                String[] tempData = new String[4];
                Student tempStudent = null;

                for(i = 0; i < tempData.length ; i++){
                    tempData = temp.split(delim);
                }
                System.out.println("DEBUG *** Finished extracting data, creating object...");
                System.out.println("DEBUG Student Data = [�" + temp + "]");

                GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
                try {
                    date = DateUtil.convertFromDMY(tempData[3]);
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                tempStudent = new Student(tempData[0], tempData[1], tempData[2], date);
                studentRecord[i] = tempStudent;
            }
        }

        return studentRecord;
    }

}
```

Driver Class:

```
public class Lab3 { 

    public void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException{

        Student[] allData = new Student[3];
        allData = (Student[]) StudentDAO.readTextData();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("DEBUG *** Student Objects created, displaying all Students...\n");
        for(Student s : allData){
            Print.print(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**
Thanks for pointing out that error, thanks everyone, but now I'm getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Is that because StudentDAO has no main?

**another edit**

@mprabhat thanks for pointing out a really stupid error, still don't know how I didn't see that ><

Now I have an issue when the scanner attempts to read the data in from the file.

1 - says data file can't be found, even though it's in my src folder.

2 - error on the scanner line as well, should I not be using a scanner on a file? should I be going with ... DataInputStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `readTextData` is not static but you are accessing it like a static method by using class name `StudentDAO`

```
StudentDAO.readTextData();
```

Instead create an object `StudentDAO` and then call `readTextData`

```
Student[] allData = new Student[3];
StudentDAO studentDAO  = new StudentDAO();
allData = (Student[]) studentDAO.readTextData();
```

Issue in your Lab3 is that you dont have correct signature of your main method.

`public static void main(String[] args)` is the correct signature, your signature is missing `static`, hence you are getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

Comment: all the comments here point to the same thing, so thank you all for the responses, but the proposed changes lead to:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Comment: @RejectionHurts updated my post, add static to your main method it and it will work

Comment: how the HELL did i miss that?! lol... i feel like an idiot now

Comment: rofl... glad you got it working... hope this settles your issues

Comment: @RejectionHurts please mark answer which helped you as correct ;)

Comment: oh i will, soon as i actually get the damn program working lol... i just got issues with the data file being opened now. the rest of the program has been unchanged, other than rearranged, so once that's up and running it should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In the class Lab3, create and instance of StudentDAO and then read the text as below:

```
StudentDAO dao = new StudentDAO();
allData = (Student[]) dao.readTextData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 things basically:

1. `readTextData()` is not static, hence you can't access it in the same manner you are doing. You will need to create an object and then call that method.
2. You are creating an array of 3 elements you are then discarding and populating with some new data.

So basically you need to replace this:

```
Student[] allData = new Student[3];
allData = (Student[]) StudentDAO.readTextData();
```

with this:

```
StudentDAO sDao = new StudentDAO();
Student[] students = (Student[])sDao.readTextData();
```

For completeness sake, if you do as follows you should also get rid of the error, but I would recommend you stick with the approach I have just listed above:

In your interface class replace this: `public Object[] readTextData() throws FileNotFoundException;` with this:  `public static Object[] readTextData() throws FileNotFoundException;`. This will make your `readTextData` method static. Replacing the method signature in your DAO (with `public static Object[] readTextData() throws FileNotFoundException;`) class should then remove the error you are facing.